# R package "scholar" / getting the citation history of an article

Tags: r, google-scholar

I have a problem with the R package [scholar](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/scholar/index.html)

**What works:**

```
get_citation_history(SSalzberg)
```

**What doesn't:**

```
get_article_cite_history(SSalzberg, "any article")
```

**Code**:

```
article <- "Ultrafast and memory-efficient alignment of short DNA sequences to the human genome"
SSalzberg <- "sUVeH-4AAAAJ" (Google Scholar ID)
get_article_cite_history(SSalzberg, article)
```

**Error Message:**

```
Error in min(years):max(years) : result would be too long a vector
In addition: Warning messages:
1: In min(years) : no non-missing arguments to min; returning Inf
2: In max(years) : no non-missing arguments to max; returning -Inf
```

I do not understand the error message in the context of that function and I tried another paper with an another author without success. I don't know what I am  missing here.... Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to use an article ID, not the title of the article.  Probably the easiest way to get this is to retrieve the full list of pubs, which has a `pubid` column ...

```
library(scholar)
SSalzberg <- "sUVeH-4AAAAJ"
all_pubs <- get_publications(SSalzberg)
## next step is cosmetic -- the equivalent of stringsAsFactors=FALSE
all_pubs <- as.data.frame(lapply(all_pubs,
         function(x) if (is.factor(x)) as.character(x) else x))
w <-grep("Ultrafast",all_pubs$title) ## publication number 3
all_pubs$title[w]
## [1] Ultrafast and memory-efficient alignment of ...
all_pubs$pubid[w] ## "Tyk-4Ss8FVUC"
ch <- get_article_cite_history(SSalzberg,all_pubs$pubid[w])
plot(cites~year,ch,type="b")
```

Comment: just for the record: the paper ID can be retrieved only from the scholar's site. In the example above the paper id would be: Tyk-4Ss8FVUC

from: 

https://scholar.google.com/citations?view_op=view_citation&hl=en&user=sUVeH-4AAAAJ&citation_for_view=sUVeH-4AAAAJ:Tyk-4Ss8FVUC

Comment: ... if this answer solves your problem you are encouraged to click the check-mark to accept it ...